# ViewPager in Fragment Update after Swipe two tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I am  new to Android Guys. I am loading The ViewPager inside the Fragment with single Tab.Onclick of Spinner it Should the update but ViewPager Update after swap two tab how to solve this?

dsfdsfdgfghghjjhjkjkhjjkhjkjkhjkjhkfhj

SetAdapter:

```
private void setViewPagerAdapter() 
{


      MyPagerAdapter adapterViewPager = new 
           MyPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
        vpPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
        vpPager.setCurrentItem(currentItemPos);

    }
```

My Adapter:

```
 public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        // Returns total number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 12;
        }

        // Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            //Log.e("position", "position>>" + position);

            return DiaryPagerFragment.newInstance(data, position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }
```

Refresh Code:

```
   Fragment frg = null;
   frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(refresh_tag);
   final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.detach(frg);
   ft.attach(frg);
   ft.commit();
```

This a the Fragment for ViewPager for Single tab
DiaryPagerFragment :

```
 public class DiaryPagerFragment extends BaseFragment {
public static final String TAG = 
DiaryPagerFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

@BindView(R.id.recycler_view)
RecyclerView recycler_view;

@BindView(R.id.tvNotFound)
TextView tvNotFound;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private FragmentListner fragmentListener;
private GetDiaryPOJO.Data data;
private int position;
private View ChildView;
private int recyclerViewItemPosition;
private int msgId;
private List<StudentListPOJO.Datum> studentList;

public DiaryPagerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static DiaryPagerFragment newInstance(GetDiaryPOJO.Data data, int pos) {
    DiaryPagerFragment fragment = new DiaryPagerFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(ARG_PARAM1, data);
    args.putInt(ARG_PARAM2, pos);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        data = (GetDiaryPOJO.Data) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_PARAM1);
        position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diary_pager, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    studentList = new ArrayList<>();
    studentList = fragmentListener.getStudentList();

    AnimationItem[] mAnimationItems = getAnimationItems();
    AnimationItem mSelectedItem = mAnimationItems[1];
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recycler_view.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recycler_view.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    setOnItemClickListener();
    setAdapter();
}

private void setOnItemClickListener() {
    recycler_view.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return true;
            }

        });

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            ChildView = Recyclerview.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
            if (ChildView != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
                recyclerViewItemPosition = Recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(ChildView);

                if (position == 0) {
                    msgId = data.getJan().get(recyclerViewItemPosition).getMsgId();
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    msgId = data.getFeb().get(recyclerViewItemPosition).getMsgId();
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    msgId = data.getMar().get(recyclerViewItemPosition).getMsgId();
                } else if (position == 3) {
                    msgId = data.getApr().get(recyclerViewItemPosition).getMsgId();
                } else if (position == 4) {
                    msgId = data.getMay().get(recyclerViewItemPosition).getMsgId();
                } else if (position == 5) {
                    msgId = data.getJun().get(recyclerViewItemPosition).getMsgId();
                } else if (position == 6) {
                    msgId = data.getJul().get(recyclerViewItemPosition).getMsgId();
                } else if (position == 7) {
                    msgId = data.getAug().get(recyclerViewItemPosition).getMsgId();
                } else if (position == 8) {
                    msgId = data.getSep().get(recyclerViewItemPosition).getMsgId();
                } else if (position == 9) {
                    msgId = data.getOct().get(recyclerViewItemPosition).getMsgId();
                } else if (position == 10) {
                    msgId = data.getNov().get(recyclerViewItemPosition).getMsgId();
                } else if (position == 11) {
                    msgId = data.getDec().get(recyclerViewItemPosition).getMsgId();
                }

                if (msgId != 0) {
                    getEventDetailRequestCall();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    });
}

private void setAdapter() {
    DiaryAdapter circularAdapter;
    if (position == 0) {
        if (data != null && data.getJan() != null && data.getJan().size() > 0) {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            circularAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(getContext(), data.getJan(), position);
            recycler_view.setAdapter(circularAdapter);
        } else {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    } else if (position == 1) {
        if (data != null && data.getFeb() != null && data.getFeb().size() > 0) {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            circularAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(getContext(), data.getFeb(), position);
            recycler_view.setAdapter(circularAdapter);
        } else {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    } else if (position == 2) {
        if (data != null && data.getMar() != null && data.getMar().size() > 0) {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            circularAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(getContext(), data.getMar(), position);
            recycler_view.setAdapter(circularAdapter);
        } else {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    } else if (position == 3) {
        if (data != null && data.getApr() != null && data.getApr().size() > 0) {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            circularAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(getContext(), data.getApr(), position);
            recycler_view.setAdapter(circularAdapter);
        } else {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    } else if (position == 4) {
        if (data != null && data.getMay() != null && data.getMay().size() > 0) {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            circularAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(getContext(), data.getMay(), position);
            recycler_view.setAdapter(circularAdapter);
        } else {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    } else if (position == 5) {
        if (data != null && data.getJun() != null && data.getJun().size() > 0) {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            circularAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(getContext(), data.getJun(), position);
            recycler_view.setAdapter(circularAdapter);
        } else {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    } else if (position == 6) {
        if (data != null && data.getJul() != null && data.getJul().size() > 0) {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            circularAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(getContext(), data.getJul(), position);
            recycler_view.setAdapter(circularAdapter);
        } else {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    } else if (position == 7) {
        if (data != null && data.getAug() != null && data.getAug().size() > 0) {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            circularAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(getContext(), data.getAug(), position);
            recycler_view.setAdapter(circularAdapter);
        } else {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    } else if (position == 8) {
        if (data != null && data.getSep() != null && data.getSep().size() > 0) {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            circularAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(getContext(), data.getSep(), position);
            recycler_view.setAdapter(circularAdapter);
        } else {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    } else if (position == 9) {
        if (data != null && data.getOct() != null && data.getOct().size() > 0) {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            circularAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(getContext(), data.getOct(), position);
            recycler_view.setAdapter(circularAdapter);
        } else {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    } else if (position == 10) {
        if (data != null && data.getNov() != null && data.getNov().size() > 0) {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            circularAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(getContext(), data.getNov(), position);
            recycler_view.setAdapter(circularAdapter);
        } else {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    } else if (position == 11) {
        if (data != null && data.getDec() != null && data.getDec().size() > 0) {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            circularAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(getContext(), data.getDec(), position);
            recycler_view.setAdapter(circularAdapter);
        } else {
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        fragmentListener = (FragmentListner) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement MyInterface ");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

// Request Rest Client API Call For SignIn
public void getEventDetailRequestCall() {
    hideKeyboard();

    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
    RestClient restClientAPI = apiClient.getClient();

    Call<GetEventDetailsPOJO> call = restClientAPI.getEventDetailsForParent(studentList.get(fragmentListener.getAppPreferenceHelper().getTopTitlePosition()).getOrgId(),
            studentList.get(fragmentListener.getAppPreferenceHelper().getTopTitlePosition()).getAcademicId(), studentList.get(fragmentListener.getAppPreferenceHelper().getTopTitlePosition()).getStudentId(),
            msgId, studentList.get(fragmentListener.getAppPreferenceHelper().getTopTitlePosition()).getSectionId(),
            MODE_GET_MESSAGE);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<GetEventDetailsPOJO>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<GetEventDetailsPOJO> call, @NonNull Response<GetEventDetailsPOJO> response) {
            GetEventDetailsPOJO getEventDetailsPOJO = response.body();
            int code = response.code();
            Log.e(TAG, "code>>>>" + code);
            if (code == RESPONSE_CODE) {
                if (getEventDetailsPOJO.getResponseCode().equals(API_RESPONSE_CODE_WITH_DATA)) {
                    if (getEventDetailsPOJO.getResponseStatus().equals(TRUE)) {
                        showDialog(getEventDetailsPOJO.getData());
                    } else {
                        showMessage(getEventDetailsPOJO.getResponseMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    showMessage(getEventDetailsPOJO.getResponseMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<GetEventDetailsPOJO> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Throwable>>>>" + t.getMessage());
            showMessage(getString(R.string.internet_not_available));
        }
    });
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void showDialog(final List<GetEventDetailsPOJO.Datum> data) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    String start_date = convertDateStringFormat2(data.get(0).getStart());
    String end_date = convertDateStringFormat2(data.get(0).getEnd());

    TextView tvTitle = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    tvTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(data.get(0).getTitle()));
    TextView tvDes = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvDes);
    tvDes.setText(Html.fromHtml(data.get(0).getDescription()));
    TextView tvStartDate = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvStartDate);
    tvStartDate.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.start_date_txt) + start_date);
    TextView tvEndDate = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvEndDate);
    tvEndDate.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.end_date_txt) + end_date);

    ImageView imgDownload = dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgDownload);

    if (!data.get(0).getAttachment().equals("") && !data.get(0).getGenFile().equals("")) {
        imgDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        imgDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    imgDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
                    + File.separator
                    + getString(R.string.app_name) + File.separator, data.get(0).getAttachment());

            if (outputFile.exists()) {
                fragmentListener.getFileDownloadCall("", data.get(0).getAttachment());
            } else {
                if (data.get(0).getGenFile().startsWith("Cir")) {
                    fragmentListener.getFileDownloadCall(ROOT_DOWNLOAD
                            + ROOT_GROUP_FOLDER
                            + studentList.get(fragmentListener.getAppPreferenceHelper().getTopTitlePosition()).getOrgId()
                            + FILE_ROOT_PATH_CIRCULAR
                            + data.get(0).getGenFile(), data.get(0).getAttachment());
                } else {
                    fragmentListener.getFileDownloadCall(ROOT_DOWNLOAD
                            + ROOT_GROUP_FOLDER
                            + studentList.get(fragmentListener.getAppPreferenceHelper().getTopTitlePosition()).getOrgId()
                            + FILE_ROOT_PATH_ASSIGNMENT
                            + data.get(0).getGenFile(), data.get(0).getAttachment());
                }
            }
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After setup adapter try to notify your adapter. 
when notify then set manually current position.

```
    MyPagerAdapter adapterViewPager = new 
    MyPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
    vpPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    vpPager.setCurrentItem(currentItemPos);
    adapterViewPager.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after this apply `addOnPageChangeListener()`

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            adapterViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

   // for add multiple fragment in viewpaget



 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Log.e("position", "position>>" + position);
       switch(position){
       case 0:
            FragmentOne one = new FragmentOne();
           return one;

        case 1:
            FragmentTwo two = new FragmentTwo();
           return two ;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: can you explain `return DiaryPagerFragment.newInstance(data, position);` this?

Comment: it is a fragment for single tab ViewPager

Comment: you have to add your fragment based on position. might be it is creating issue.

Comment: i have added DiaryPagerFragment check out

Comment: if you know any other way to refresh ,Suggest me

Comment: try to add multiple fragment based on position n check its refreshing or not.

Comment: how to  Add Multiple Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

In your viewPager Adapter extends `FragmentPagerAdapter` this and include these methods and it will give new ID to every Fragment and when you add manually data in array and call `notifyDataSetChange()`, also call this method `notifyChangeInPosition(mItems.size() - 1);`.

From this the added item get a new ID.

```
  private long baseId = 0;

    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }
//this is called when notifyDataSetChanged() is called
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        // refresh all fragments when data set changed
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // give an ID different from position when position has been changed
        return baseId + position;
    }

    /**
     * Notify that the position of a fragment has been changed.
     * Create a new ID for each position to force recreation of the fragment
     *
     * @param n number of items which have been changed
     */
    void notifyChangeInPosition(int n) {
        // shift the ID returned by getItemId outside the range of all previous fragments
        baseId += getCount() + n;
    }
```

Comment: there is no Method like notifyChangeInPosition. My  ViewPagerAdapter extends  FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: bro see code snippet last method that was notifyChangeInPosition() method call.

Comment: No bro In My Code i am not getting notifyChangeInPosition()

Comment: @SivaBalan its custom method not super method like notifyDataSetChaged() It's written by me in code snippset. Please copy these methods in you adapter to get fully working adapter